# Why aren't Syntax Highlighting and Line Highlighting getting along in Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, lisp, emacs24

I'm having an issue similar to the one described here:

[Disable hl-line in Emacs when using Emacs Starter Kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545458/disable-hl-line-in-emacs-when-using-emacs-starter-kit)

I am using Emacs 24 for OS X ( http://emacsformacosx.com/ ), invoked with the -nw flag to run it in the terminal (so I can have true fullscreen).  I started my customizations with the Emacs Starter Kit ( https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit ). Most of the things I've added are working well.

However, I have noticed that my syntax highlighting doesn't display when the selected line is highlighted (all the text is the same color).  I like the `line-highlight` effect but don't want to give up syntax highlighting.  Is there any way to accomplish this (particularly in the terminal)?

My syntax/background coloring is done using `custom-theme`.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:  I'm using Lion.

Comment: You can have "true full screen" by using Homebrew.  It's ridiculous to use Emacs in a console when you don't have to do it.

Comment: True fullscreen with Emacs 24?  My first attempt at a Homebrew build didn't end too well IIRC.

Comment: I have Googled around regarding this extensively, and sifting through the vast corpus of knowledge (much of it obsolete) about Emacs on the web is no small chore!

Comment: IIRC `--with-cocao` was useful.  I don't use the NS build any more, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you have to customize your `hl-line` face using `M-x customize-face RET hl-line`. Then make-sure it has no other property (not even the `inherit` property) and all it defines is a background-color. The highlighted lines should be highlighted with that background colour, but letting the existing syntax highlighting shine through.

Another approach is to use the "solarized" themes found at https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized/. These already take care of the issue.

EDIT: Actually you can leave the `inherit` property, just make sure that face doesn't override the properties that you want to shine through as syntax highlighting.

Comment: I think this will lead me to the solution, thanks.  Now I just have to figure out all these parameters- off to the docs I go!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stab in the dark since we don't know what version of OS X you are using. Prior to Lion, Terminal.app did not support 256 colors, so:

1. Does it work well in Emacs.app?
2. If so, are you running a version of OS X prior to Lion?

   - If yes and you don't want to (or can't) upgrade your OS: try using [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/) as your terminal and see how emacs works then.
   - If no: perhaps someone else can offer assistance.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering.  I am using Lion (I have updated the question to reflect this) and I am using iTerm2, with the terminal type set to `xterm-256color`.  The syntax highlighting / colors work just fine unless the line is highlighted.